# What are the capabilities of Salesforce Professional Edition in comparison to Group Edition ? I need all the details

Tags: professional-edition

What are the capabilities of Salesforce Professional Edition in comparison to Group Edition ? I need all the details. If some one can provide detailed information ??

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below URLs for complete details.

http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf
https://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf